# How to remove gameObjects once they are out of screen

Tags: unity, 3d

My game has a player that keeps running forward automatically.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 position = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(transform.position);

    if (position.x < 0 || position.x > 1 || position.y < 0 || position.y > 1)
    {
        OnBecameInvisible();
    }
}

void OnBecameInvisible()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

With this solution I'm able to remove the objects behind me and the ones out of the screen. The problem is that it also removes the gameObjects far away (if I turn the camera everything gets removed).

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered disabling the gameobjects when they get out of the viewport and then reenabling them when they get in the viewport again?

Comment: You're checking to see if the *center* of the object is on screen. This is insufficient, especially for large objects. [Maybe this will help](https://answers.unity.com/questions/8003/how-can-i-know-if-a-gameobject-is-seen-by-a-partic.html).

Comment: How are you suppose to manage this anyway? Any reason you want to remove objects? You could set a bool on when it becomes visible and only then remove on onbecomeinvisible

Comment: Unity already has a function called [`OnBecameInvisible`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html) automatically called when the renderer is not rendered anymore by any camera.

Comment: If your concerns are performance related, I suggest doing a profiling run, where you don't remove any objects at first and then you try and remove objects. In case of Unity, it should already have culling for objects out of screen, so there shouldn't really be any overhead for this.

Answer (score 2):

there is a nice built in renderer is visible check that you can use. instead of checking against the position you can just check if it is visible by any scene cameras

In your case you can simply check if they are not visible and then call your OnBecameInvisible method.

```
if(!GetComponent<Renderer>().isVisible) {
    OnBecameInvisible();
}
```

Comment: nice so glad i clicked this! did not know that

Comment: Note: Be sure to fetch your renderer in `Start()` and cache it! That is, don't call `GetComponent<Renderer>()` in `Update()` because it is unnecessary overhead.